# 'hibernate' doesn't work on xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, swap

I've just installed Xubuntu on my laptop.
All works fine except that hibernating doesn't work.
I (successfully) resized the swap partition with GParted but it's still the same.
When restarting the computer after hibernating the programs from last session are displayed but the computer doesn't respond anymore and I have to reboot.
Could anyone please help me. I need the 'hibernate'-function.

Comment: use the `pm-hibernate`command in terminal. if it works then it means hibernation works for you.

Comment: tried it. doesn't work. after reawaking the display freezes.

Comment: so hibernation works, But after the awake it freezes ? Am I correct ?

Comment: yes. hibernation works, awake not

Comment: Yeah, solved the problem.

To all who have the same problem, try:
Change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" in '/etc/default/grub' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" and then update grub.

For me it worked perfectly well.

Comment: Wow, GJ. Can you share your solution below so that others can use it in the future ?

Comment: tried countless things, this was the first one that really worked